# VM Virtual Box 32 bit OS on 64 hardware

Tags: 32bit-64bit, virtualbox, windows-2000

I need to install Windows 2000 + SQL Server 2000 to do some development using Classic ASP that connects to a SQL 2000 database for a client.

They have an old machine they want to use for the project. Long story that would bore you.

I have Windows 2000 and SQL 2000 but they are old 32 bit and my system is a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Is Virtual box capable of running on the 64 bit machine in "32 bit" mode? I have tried installing Windows 2000 but get a blue screen each time.

My guess is VM Box is incapable of doing this, is there any possible way to get this to work as all I need to do is have SQL Server 2000 so that I can export the db file for upload to their test server, the actual web files can reside on my Windows 7 PC as long as they can connect to the database.

TIA
John

Comment: Do you have VT enabled in your BIOS on the Host Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run a 32 bit OS just fine using 64 bit VirtualBox.